# Get all keys that appear on multiple redis sorted sets

Tags: php, redis

I have multiple sorted sets on redis that contain a user ID and a score. Is there any way I can filter and fetch user IDs that appear on multiple sets? For example if the lists looked like this

```
List A - u1, u2, u3, u4, u5
List B - u3, u4, u5
List C - u4, u2, u3
List D - u4, u1, u2
```

1. If I feed in list A, B, C, D then the only user ID that should appear is u4
2. And if I feed in list A, B, C then the user IDs that are returned are u4, u3.

I can imaging doing this in PHP by loading each list and filtering out each list till I am left with the IDs I want, but is there any way I can carry out this operation in Redis?

I am also open to new ways of storing this structure in redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In set theory, it's called intersection. Redis has a [ZINTERSTORE](http://redis.io/commands/zinterstore) command that intersects the keys of multiple sorted sets and stores them into a new key.

```
ZINTERSTORE LIST-Z 4 A B C D
ZRANGE LIST-Z 0 -1 WITHSCORES
```

This intersects the users from keys A, B, C and D and stores the intersection in key LIST-Z

Comment: Thanks for this, I think this is the way to go. Been playing around with this and I'm getting the results that I expect.